# Factory reset my RCA Viking Neptune 10 tablet

Tags: factory-reset

Trying to factory reset my RCA Viking Neptune 10 tablet it has no volume button, no home button, only a power on button and detachable keyboard. Any suggestions are truly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a home button?

Comment: Or a pinhole with "reset" printed near it?

Comment: Thank you helper, there is no home button on the tablet. There are some holes on the back of the tablet but none are marked. If I find which one is the reset what would I do please?

Comment: Would reading the user manual tell you this? RCA publishes pdf files for their models.

Answer (score 0):

As wbogacz suggested i found the user manual and found out that there is a reset button which can be located at number 9 of the following image of the backside of the device:

[image]

Press that button to reset the tablet (then press and hold the
Power button for 4~5 seconds to turn on the
unit).

Hope this solved your query.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone! It is so strange I tried to press the reset button with a pin and then turn on the power and I still see the same message - "to start android enter your password" How long do you need to press the reset button? Maybe there is something I am missing. Thank you so much!!!